# Different dynamic links for different apps on the same firebase project/console/account

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to know how we can have separate dynamic links for 2 separate apps on the same Firebase account. I have 2 apps right now and when I use the dynamic link with app-site-association, I can see that the same dynamic link talks to 2 different app IDS. Is there a way to make sure we can have 2 dynamic links which opens two appIds on the same project on Firebase.